# Why does NumPy dot product use second-to-last axis of the second array?

Tags: python, numpy

I was reading the documentation for [numpy.dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), and it says, verbatim:

> If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:
>
> `dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])`

I tried it out for larger dimensions, and it checks out:

```py
k = 2
A = np.random.rand(3, 5, 7, k)
B = np.random.rand(9, 11, k, 13)

np.dot(A, B).shape  # Shows `(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13)`
```

**Can someone explain why is it defined that way?** That is, why is the "second-to-last" axis of matrix `b` (not first)? If it is an optimization / acceleration trick, I would really appreciate an explanation for that, if possible :)

Comment: `dot` is best defined for 2d arrays, where 2nd to the last is the first.  `np.matmul` handling of higher dimensions is generally more useful than `np.dot`.

Comment: The documentation of the `np.matmul` certainly makes sense. But I am referring to the `np.dot`'s way of handing N-D by M-D sum product -- I just cannot wrap my mind around the reasoning here :'(

Comment: They are the same in handling the 2nd to the last dimension of `B`.  `dot` does a kind of 'outer' product in the other dimensions, and usually it's not very useful.  That's largely why `matmul` was added.